# OpenSUSE 11 server as a router

Tags: router, opensuse

So, I've been trying for a longer time to set up the server as front-end router for my local network. It's because my server has quite a lot of multimedia on it downloaded a LOT, and the current router is just not enough. I don't want to buy a new router, because those that might be enough are quite expensive. Fortunately, I saw a few setups where the server works as the router itself.

My new setup would then look like this:

```
WAN - IPS -|-> My server -> Home router -> Local computer 1
             ^                             Local computer 2
             '- possibly a switch          ...
```

I did a search and luckily found [this tutorial](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/11505.html), describing the very same setup - an OpenSUSE server functioning as a router. However, I noticed that the tutorial is a bit off, mainly because I have a different version of YaST on my server.

However, I tried my best to follow it, using lower leveled commands (using terminal) to accomplish the same. It took a bit longer, but I thought the result was the same.

Unfortunately, it didn't work.

This is what I managed so far:

- Two network cards, one on board, one a PCI device, running at /dev/eth0 (on board, inner one) and /dev/eth1 (PCI, outer one).
- eth1 is set with DHCP address, easily acquires IP address from ISP (I have a static one, so it's always the same one) and connects. This one definitely works, because I can use the internet on the server itself.
- eth0 is set with a static IP of 192.168.0.1.
- <s>DHCP server, running on eth0 - works, computers connected get IP addresses, even though the DHCP server on the router is turned off.</s>

Apparently now not even the DHCP server works. I am using this ISC DHCP server, not sure if it's the best choice though.

The last part I need is to somehow bridge or connect the two cards, so that I can access the internet via eth1 from computers connected (via the router) to eth0. In the tutorial this is just made using "masquerading", or allowing the internal zone (eth0) to access internet via the external zone (eth1). Apparently this part is the same in both version of YaST, mine and the one in the tutorial. I think, however, this doesn't work. I've tried to use YaST to set this up, then I used terminal, but with no difference.

I suppose the masquerading itself might work, but the computers don't connect right? Or it's the fault in masquerading. Anyways, using ping, I can ping 192.168.0.1 with a very fast and successful response.

What am I doing wrong? Please feel free to ask anything (most likely I forgot something), I'd be happy to respond...

iptables -L:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED 
input_int  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
input_ext  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
input_int  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-IN-ILL-TARGET ' 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
TCPMSS     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN TCPMSS clamp to PMTU 
forward_int  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
forward_ext  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-FWD-ILL-ROUTING ' 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-OUT-ERROR ' 

Chain forward_ext (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED icmp echo-reply 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED icmp destination-unreachable 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED icmp time-exceeded 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED icmp parameter-problem 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED icmp timestamp-reply 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED icmp address-mask-reply 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED icmp protocol-unreachable 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED icmp redirect 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            PKTTYPE = multicast 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            PKTTYPE = broadcast 
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-FWDext-DROP-DEFLT ' 
LOG        icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-FWDext-DROP-DEFLT ' 
LOG        udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 state NEW LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-FWDext-DROP-DEFLT ' 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain forward_int (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED icmp echo-reply 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED icmp destination-unreachable 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED icmp time-exceeded 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED icmp parameter-problem 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED icmp timestamp-reply 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED icmp address-mask-reply 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED icmp protocol-unreachable 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED icmp redirect 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            PKTTYPE = multicast 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            PKTTYPE = broadcast 
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-FWDint-DROP-DEFLT ' 
LOG        icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-FWDint-DROP-DEFLT ' 
LOG        udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 state NEW LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-FWDint-DROP-DEFLT ' 
reject_func  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain input_ext (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            PKTTYPE = broadcast 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp source-quench 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request 
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 tcp dpt:ftp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP ' 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ftp 
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 tcp dpt:ssh flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP ' 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh 
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 tcp dpt:lm-x flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP ' 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:lm-x 
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 tcp dpt:http flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP ' 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:lm-x 
LOG        tcp  --  192.168.0.1          anywhere            tcp spt:lm-x dpt:lm-x state NEW limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-INext-ACC ' 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.0.1          anywhere            tcp spt:lm-x dpt:lm-x 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            PKTTYPE = multicast 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            PKTTYPE = broadcast 
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT ' 
LOG        icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT ' 
LOG        udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 state NEW LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT ' 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain input_int (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain reject_func (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with tcp-reset 
REJECT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable
```

iptables -t nat -L:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

DHCP server configuration:

```
authoritative;

subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
   range 192.168.0.100 192.168.0.200;
   option ip-forwarding on;
   default-lease-time 7200;
   max-lease-time 86400;
   option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
   option broadcast-address 192.168.0.255;
   option routers 192.168.0.1;
   option domain-name "domain-local.sk"; # I really don't know what should I put here.
   option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.1;
}
```

Comment: `iptables -L ; iptables -t nat -L`

Comment: Hold on a second, starting up the server.

Comment: Added the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you just need to enable IPv4-forwarding (routing) like this:

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

(default value is 0 there. I setup debian as a firewall 2 days ago and this helped ;))

**EDIT**

This script saves and deletes all entries in your iptables and sets up a basic configuration for masquerading from the inner network.

```
#!/bin/bash
# saving old iptables-configuration
iptables-save > /home/xxusernamexx/iptables-saved.out

# delete all existing rules and chains
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -X
iptables -Z
iptables -t nat -Z

# setting up masquerade
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE

# forwarding for answer-packages from the internet
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG --log-ip-options --log-prefix fwd-drop
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP

# allowing loopback and internal connections
# uncommend the following line if you want to allow ping from external
iptables -A INPUT -s 0.0.0.0/0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT # for your webserver
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT # edited
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -i eth1 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT # for connections from lan-nic
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-ip-options --log-prefix io-drop
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT # edited
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -o eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-ip-options --log-prefix io-drop
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP

# just to make sure that routing is enabled
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Try this script. I can't really test it, because my eth1-eth0 interfaces are used the other way, but I wrote this script based on my own configuration.
To be save, this script exports your actual iptables-configuration to your home-folder.
It can be recovered using *iptables-restore < filename*

*EDIT*: added `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT` and deleted `-m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED` in OUTPUT's first rule in order to allow the server to make own connections in every net (i.e. for query a DNS-server)

*EDIT2*: The problem is solved.
There were a few misconfigured things:

**iptables**: We had to change the script a little bit to get it fully working (edited it in my answer as well).

**DHCP**: dhcpd was configured to use '192.168.0.1' as DNS-server. But the server didn't run a DNS-Server. We configured it to ISP-DNS-servers.

**Router**: The server was plugged in at the WAN-Port of the router. That brought the router to drop several packets from the clients to the server (and back). Aurel plugged it into a LAN-Port and it worked.

Comment: Did that already.

Comment: Then please post your output for Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams command (in the comment under your question). Did you set your OpenSUSE-box as default-gateway for your clients?

Comment: Yes, that's set up in the DHCP server configuration.

Comment: ok, then we need the output just mentioned. Does your ping from a client say, that there is no route available or does it say, that it can't resolve the host (like google)?

Comment: cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward : 1

Comment: be patient, I'm writing a script for your right now, that sets up a basic rule-set for iptables.

Comment: Hm... not sure if this worked. Couldn't start eth1 with these tables, had to restore. Also I am getting this error while starting eth1: Error while executing:
   Command 'ip route replace to -.0.0.0/24 via 91.148.24.1 dev eth1' returned:
  Error: an inet prefix is expected rather than "-.0.0.0/24".
   Configuration line: - 91.148.24.1 255.255.255.0 eth1

Comment: "-.0.0.0/24" is no valid subnet. Is this a typo in any of your configurations? It should be "0.0.0.0/24". This doesn't come from my script. You could retry my script when you fixed this error/typo.

Comment: Yeah, had a small bit when I was trying to do this before... Removed it. Anyways, using your set up, it first outputted "too many links" four times. I thought it was because the network was running, but I am not so sure about it. However, I stopped it, ran the script, and restarted the network... Not working at all... Can't connect to any website from this machine with those tables. So had to restore again.

Comment: I still feel that I maybe did something wrong. Do you have a set up script or something? That would definitely help.

Comment: sorry, my fault. iptables -F has to be called first (edited it in my script). "too many links" showed up, because my script tried to delete chains, that were linked in other chains. Sadly I can't provide anything other than this, because iptables is distribution-independant. I can't help you with SUSE-specific things (like YAST) because I'm a debian-guy ;) *EDIT*: when we made sure, that iptables is correctly configured, I could try to help you with other configuration-issues (if there are any).

Comment: btw: you don't have to take your network down in order to configure iptables. You can leave it up.

Comment: No, still doesn't work. There was that "iptalbes" error, fixed it, but that's not the problem. After restoring and running the fixed script again (and restarting network just in case) the internet still does not work - "Server can not be found." is FF response. Also, I think I have to restart the network, because after running the restore, nothing happened until I restarted the network.

Comment: "Server not found" is a DNS-Error. Do you provide a DNS-Server in your DHCP-configuration? You could try to ping 209.85.149.104 (google). If you get an answer on your client, you can say, that your routing and filtering/masquerading is ok. You then have to make sure that your clients have valid DNS-servers configured. (regarding my rules: these are nearly exact the same like on my linux-box (I've got a few additional DNAT-rules) - they should work)

Comment: I am testing the web on the server right now. If that would work, I would then test it on a client.

Comment: Sorry, I just discovered one problem (edited the script already). It wasn't possible for the linux-box to make own connections (OUTPUT was droped). If your server has problems to update his DNS-records (if there is bind9 or any dns-server installed) or just ping any machine, then update your iptables rules with my updated script. Sorry again.

Comment: Okay, that seems to have fixed this one problem...

Comment: Now there is another one -.- The DHCP server seems not to be working. On my router I get an error saying "Internet adressing learnt thru DHCP conflicts with LAN adressing." - I think the DHCP server is incorrectly configured. Posting configuration now.

Comment: Okay, that means, ping goes through from the server? Is it possible to ping google from a client (maybe with a static ip to make sure the network is ok)? For your DHCP-issue please post your ifconfig-output.

Comment: No. NOW I got the "no route to host"

Comment: From which machine? btw: is thenet.sk pointing to your server? Do you host your website or other services at this server? (then we need additional iptables-rules)

Comment: From a client connected to the router connected to the server. And yes, this is the server of thenet.sk, where I host my web and stuff.

Comment: May I ssh into your server to check all configuration? (this is getting very long) I'd edit my post and add the solution (whatever it'll be). You can contact me via mail (meik@schnitzelspecht.de) or IM wullxz@jabber.ccc.de (jabber) 301399429 (ICQ)

Comment: Sent you a mail.